# Config.php -error when logging in

Tags: bolt-cms

After updating to 2.1.7 I get an error in the backend saying

" Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /domains/domaindomain.nl/DEFAULT/src/Config.php on line 641

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /domains/ityhardy.nl/DEFAULT/src/Config.php:641) in /domains/ityhardy.nl/DEFAULT/src/Users.php on line 287
"

Using SQLite on this site.

Frontend seems to work fine.

I must add that at the time of updating I was making small changes in contenttypes.yml, don't know in which exact order I did what.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: There was a stray “uses” in the wrong field somewhere in contenttypes.yml